# SvelteKit How to Reload Current Page via the Client Side Router using Goto?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

It appears that `goto` in SvelteKit does not do anything when it is instructed to redirect to the current webpage:

```
<script>
    import { goto, invalidate } from '$app/navigation';

    function reloadPage() {
        const thisPage = window.location.pathname;
        console.log('goto ' + thisPage);
        goto(thisPage);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={() => reloadPage()}>
    Reload
</button>
```

In addition, I've tried `invalidate`, as well as `invalidate` followed by a `goto`, as well as `goto` with adding fake query parameters, and none of them will cause the page to refresh.

The only way I can get it working is by calling `location.reload()`, however this will bypass SvelteKit's client side routing and go back to the server, reloading the entire app over the network.

Answer (score 10):

You should not use `goto`, instead use [`invalidateAll`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall).

If your page does not appear to update correctly, you are not using the `data` reactively, i.e. some value is set once and does not update when the `data` is re-loaded.

Comment: this doesn't work when using load function at +page.server.ts

Comment: @Molem Whether it is in `+page` or `+page.server` should not matter at all. (Tested with server file and works just fine.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround, by chaining `goto`, but there must be a better way:

```
    function reloadPage() {
        const thisPage = window.location.pathname;

        console.log('goto ' + thisPage);

        goto('/').then(
            () => goto(thisPage)
        );
    }
```

Comment: it works cool when using load function at +page.server.ts